# WIX Local AppData Settings

Tags: xml, installation, wix, windows-installer, settings

I am using Windows Installer XML to make a .msi. The installer turned out just fine. The problem is that the name of our company contains 2 words and a space. WIX is adding "_" instead of the space. So the old settings remain in the old folder. So how can I define the settings folder name in WIX ?

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
          <Directory Id="DIRECTORY" Name="COMPANY NAME">
            <Directory Id="APP_APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="APP NAME" />
          </Directory>
            <!-- c:\program files\COMPANY NAME\APP NAME -->
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
```

Comment: Can you post the code snippet how you set the company name, and what's there in the output MSI file in that place?

Comment: I posted it, nothing out of the ordinary, really

Comment: Which version of WiX are you using?

Comment: 3.7 - the latest I'm guessing

Answer (score 0):

Have a wix includes file and set the name there like so:

```
<?define Manufacturer = "Whatever your company is"?>
```

use it like this:

```
<Directory Id="DIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer )">
```